# json_decode error, not able to run a foreach loop

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3

I am in a trouble with API development with Laravel 5.3.

My application is a shopping app, after verify the cart need to submit the cart details and customer details to server through an API.

**Android PostData in LogCat**

```
{"customer_id":378,"customer_shipping_id":487,"order_amount":13.5,"cashback":0,"store_id":134,"delivery_amount":0.0,"currency":133,"coupon":"","product_array":"[\"{\\\"product_id\\\":933,\\\"product_quantity\\\":1,\\\"product_name\\\":\\\"7up Cherry 330ml\\\",\\\"total\\\":3.5}\",\"{\\\"product_id\\\":722,\\\"product_quantity\\\":1,\\\"product_name\\\":\\\"A&W Root Beer Aged Vanilla 355ml\\\",\\\"total\\\":10.0}\"]"}
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
  $customer_id     = Input::get('customer_id');
  $shipping_id     = Input::get('customer_shipping_id');
  $amount          = Input::get('order_amount');
  $cashback        = Input::get('cashback');
  $store_id        = Input::get('store_id');
  $delivery_charge = Input::get('delivery_amount');
  $coupon          = Input::get('coupon');
  $currency_id     = Input::get('currency');
  $product_array   = json_decode(Input::get('product_array'));

  foreach ($product_array as $item) {
    $res[]= $item['product_id'];
  }
  $response= [

        'status' => 200,
        'result' => [
          'product_ids' => $res
        ]
    ];
  return $response;
```

I can get all keys except **product_array** and not able to loop with the foreach.

**var_dump(Input::get('product_array'));**

[image]

Comment: the json your shown very first is not correct and its showing error on `product_array`. check here:-http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Anant I cleared the error in json and its getting error now as "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @Anant json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(Input::get('product_array'));`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung updated question with var_dump(Input::get('product_array'));

Comment: @Anant Still app team getting "invalid argument supplied foreach", but I can get success result in postman, there is no issues..

Comment: @Jishad  you have posted two outputs of `var_dump(Input::get('product_array'));` it's confusing to understand which one is actual output?

Comment: @Anant, you mean the postman response ?

Comment: You need to recover the exact request from your App team's problem. Maybe you should log the raw input somehow to further debug.

Comment: @KoalaYeung please check the updated question for the exact postdata

Comment: The Android's PostData is not a valid JSON. That's the problem. Please make sure they're using proper library to generate it.

Comment: Especially the product array. It is not an array. It seems to be a string represetentation of an array. But there are multiple string escaping and hence the multiple `\` inside of it.

Comment: I see the Input::get('product_array') value look like array so if you remove json_decode  when you get the value. it should work.